# Rewrite rules appear to be ignored

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The hosting FAQ page found here http://www.freewebhostingarea.com/faq.html says:

> Yes, we have full .htaccess support.
>   Mod_rewrite is enabled and you will be able to use permalinks or any other rule.

So in my `.htaccess` file I have:

```
Options ExecCGI Includes IncludesNOEXEC SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes
#Options -Indexes
#Options All -Indexes     <------------- I've also tried these commented lines
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php      
RewriteEngine On      

# Taking the advice of early posters to simplify my two rules into one
# my current rewrite rule is:

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ viewpost.php?category=$1&number=$2

# Below were my original re-write rules when I posted this question: 
#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ viewpost.php?category=$1&number=$2
#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ viewpost.php?category=$1&number=$2
```

The only line that works is the 404 page I put in (line 4), I assume I can't prevent a directory listing probably because the server doesn't allow overrides.

I can't actually find a statement anywhere that says I can't, but It's a free host, so I just assumed so.

But their FAQ specifically states I can use mod rewrite (maybe I'm misunderstanding?).

When I type in:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/s/1
```

I simply get my 404 page rather than having it written to

```
viewpost.php?etc...
```

> @user2734435 what is your folder structure?

I have most of my php files in my root folder. I have a folder for images, and I have a folder for post content for each category.

All the relevent files that I believe are immediately/obviously relevent for this problem are in the root folder  (there may be other things that are relevent that I've missed, but I've tried to cover all my bases above). my viewpost.php, my .htaccess my 404.php (not really relevent but Included because that's the only line that DOES work as intended in the file.)

> domain on public_html?

It's a free host. there's no public_html. The scope I have access to with this webhost is probably the public_html.  I place my index in the "root" folder, and that's what shows up when visit my domain.

> where is your php files?

"root" folder I described above.

> where is your .htaccess file?

Root folder. I have no other .htaccess file

> do you have any other .htaccess files on other directories?

See above.

Comment: Is there any reason to write same rule twice ?

Comment: the second rule isn't the same. I have the trailing / to so that both /s/1 and s/1/ would get rewritten.   Would that cause problems though? I'll try removing one of the lines now.

Comment: Add a slash on the first one followed by a ?.

Comment: add a slash followed by a ? where?  I think the second rule covers the slash if you're saying place the slash where I think you're saying to place it.  and is the missing question mark covered by the "?" after my viewpost.php? or do i need another one somewhere else?

Comment: Those two rules are right, but they can be simplified by adding /? before the $ to the first rule.

Comment: oh. I see. thanks I'll make that change now.  Still doesn't solve the underlying problem though =( the server seems to be ignoring the rules.

Comment: @user2734435 what is your folder structure? domain on public_html? where is your php files? where is your .htaccess file? do you have any other .htaccess files on other directories? could you use the [**Edit link or click here**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18542238/edit) and update your question with this information so we can best helping finding out why it gives you 404.

Comment: @Prix  I just edited the post.   Thanks for viewing the thread and helping me out I didn't expect so many answers so fast.

Comment: @user2734435 yeah the best time to get answer is when you post your question as people will be mostly interacting with it ;) so you should always stick around for something like 10~30 minutes if possible. Give this rule a try http://pastebin.com/Bheta1gy and let me know if it works or gives you a 404 try to describe it as best as possible on what happens. If it gives you a 404 try removing this line `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` and try again.

Comment: @Skaparate so in the context you told me to use the '?' what does it mean exactly?   does it mean that the preceding symbol is optional? (it's what I have it as now after following your advice, but I'd like to know the exact meaning of the '?' to make sure you didn't misunderstand me and the rule is as I intend it)

Comment: @user2734435 the ? next to a characters means with or without that characters. so it would match `s/1/` and `s/1`. `preceding symbol is optional` yes exactly, the preceding character or group is optional.

Comment: @user2734435 does that work for you?

Comment: @Prix  Thanks! that worked. I'm so I needed the rewrite base line I'm guessing?   I still get a directory listing when I view folders with no index file, but I'm not too concerned with that (and again as stated in the question, I'm pretty sure i know why it's not working either)

strange how rewrite base doensn't default to the current directory.  Thanks again everyone!

I'm gonna start implementing now. hopefully it'll be smooth sailing from here on.

Comment: @user2734435 yes it could have been the RewriteBase but as I am using my rule it doesnt really matter because I defined `/viewpost` with a starting `/` so it should work even without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /viewpost.php?category=$1&number=$2 [L]
```

This `([^/]+)` tell you want to capture everything not a `/` as $1.

This `([0-9]+)` tells you want to catch any amount of numbers as $2.

This `/?` means the last `/` is optional.

So in short this that rule means:

```
domain.com/anythinghere/anynumberhere
```

or

```
domain.com/anythinghere/anynumberhere/
```

Rediredts to:

```
domain.com/viewpost.php?category=anythinghere&number=anynumberhere
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On      
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ viewpost.php?category=$1&number=$2
```

Comment: yeah. no difference. Still get a 404 when I do domain.com/s/1 (my simplified test case before i implement my actual categories and posts)  Why would the extra question mark be needed though? wouldn't that make the browser ignore viewpost.php ? (which is the file I need to pass the variables to)

For more context: I use the variables in viewpost.php to decide which post to display

eg. include $1.$2.php   (obviously my implementation is a bit more complicated than that. but you get the gist.

Comment: if htaccess file is inside a folder then put this line `RewriteBase /WRITE_YOUR_DIR_NAME_HERE/` after `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: my htaccess file is in the root =(